# Python: extract value from API calls try it out?

Tags: python, extract

Can anyone teach me how to extract the latitude and longitude values? How can I do that?

```
url="https://api.projectnimbus.org/neaodataservice.svc/NowcastSet"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header("accept", "*/*")
request.add_header('AccountKey', "OSJeROQjTg4v7Ec3kiecjw==")
request.add_header('UniqueUserID', "00000000000000000000000000000001")
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
for key in result.readlines():
    print key
```

Maybe storing into dict, funct, for loop ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="https://api.projectnimbus.org/NEAoDataService.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">NowcastSet</title>
  <id>https://api.projectnimbus.org/neaodataservice.svc/NowcastSet</id>
  <updated>2013-07-15T04:29:33Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="NowcastSet" href="NowcastSet" />
  <entry>
    <id>https://api.projectnimbus.org/NEAoDataService.svc/NowcastSet(1322321)</id>
    <title type="text">Ang Mo Kio</title>
    <summary type="text">Cloudy</summary>
    <updated>2013-07-15T04:29:33Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Nowcast" href="NowcastSet(1322321)" />
    <category term="NEAModel.Nowcast" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
```

I only need the values here, such as area, lat and long.

```
<m:properties>
        <d:NowcastID m:type="Edm.Int32">1322321</d:NowcastID>
        <d:Area>Ang Mo Kio</d:Area>
        <d:Condition>Cloudy</d:Condition>
        <d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">1.37315954</d:Latitude>
        <d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">103.8523865</d:Longitude>
        <d:Summary>Cloudy</d:Summary>
        <d:Distance m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:Distance>
        <d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2013-07-15T04:00:25.987</d:CreateDate>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
    <geo:lat xmlns:geo="http://www.georss.org/georss">1.37315954</geo:lat>
    <geo:long xmlns:geo="http://www.georss.org/georss">103.8523865</geo:long>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is your friend.

```
import urllib2
try:
    from bs4 import BeautifulStoneSoup #Using bs4
except ImportError:
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup #Using bs3

url="https://api.projectnimbus.org/neaodataservice.svc/NowcastSet"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header("accept", "*/*")
request.add_header('AccountKey', "OSJeROQjTg4v7Ec3kiecjw==")
request.add_header('UniqueUserID', "00000000000000000000000000000001")
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
xml_str = result.read()

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml_str)

prop_list = []
for content in soup.findAll("m:properties")
    props = {}
    for prop in content.findChildren():
        props[prop.name[2:]] = prop.text
    prop_list.append(props)

print prop_list
```

Comment: I had this error C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:348: UserWarning: The BeautifulStoneSoup class is deprecated. Instead of using it, pass features="xml" into the BeautifulSoup constructor.
  'The BeautifulStoneSoup class is deprecated. Instead of using '

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):     soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml_str)     super(BeautifulStoneSoup, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: Possibly use bs3 instead: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/download/3.x/BeautifulSoup-3.0.8/BeautifulSoup.py

Comment: I have a lot of mproperties, how do i extract all of them ? I got like 60 ?

Comment: Thanks ! Do you know how to pretty print out ? Such as Area : Ang Mo Kio \n Latitude : 1.37315954 \n Longitude : 103.8523865 ? Glad if you could help me with the last step I needed.

Comment: I have updated this question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648913/python-printing-to-a-key-pair-value-from-a-website-using-beautifulsoup