# python printing to a key pair value from a website using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pretty-print

I have this code extracted using beautifulsoup from this website https://api.projectnimbus.org/neaodataservice.svc/NowcastSet ?

After displaying all the location how do I pretty print it to a key pair value ? Like Location : Ang Mo Kio
Latitude : 1.3546846
Longitude : 103.564132 ?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup #Using bs3
import urllib2

url="https://api.projectnimbus.org/neaodataservice.svc/NowcastSet"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header("accept", "*/*")
request.add_header('AccountKey', "OSJeROQjTg4v7Ec3kiecjw==")
request.add_header('UniqueUserID', "00000000000000000000000000000001")
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
xml_str = result.read()

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml_str)

prop_list = []
for content in soup.findAll("m:properties"):
    props = {}
    for prop in content.findChildren():
        props[prop.name[2:]] = prop.text
    prop_list.append(props)

print prop_list
```

Comment: OSJeROQjTg4v7Ec3kiecjw== and 00000000000000000000000000000001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup #Using bs3

url="https://api.projectnimbus.org/neaodataservice.svc/NowcastSet"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header("accept", "*/*")
request.add_header('AccountKey', "OSJeROQjTg4v7Ec3kiecjw==")
request.add_header('UniqueUserID', "00000000000000000000000000000001")
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
xml_str = result.read()

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml_str)

prop_list = []
for content in soup.findAll("m:properties"):
    props = {}
    for prop in content.findChildren():
        props[prop.name[2:]] = prop.text
    prop_list.append(props)

for prop in prop_list:
    print "Area: %(area)s\nLat: %(latitude)s\nLong: %(longitude)s\n" % prop
```

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find` returns only the first one match, so you need [`soup.findAll`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__). As for pretty print, you can use [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html).